# Why not run tcpdump sidecar in kubernetes environment in production?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to capture the TCP packets of my application. I found that sidecar model as explained in [sidecars-analyze-debug-network-traffic-kubernetes-pod](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/02/27/sidecars-analyze-debug-network-traffic-kubernetes-pod/) fits nicely to my application. I would like to know the reasons why something like this should not be done in the production? Basically what are the downside of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can run it if convenient for you. Of course additional container will use additional resources in your cluster, but if you can afford it - why not?

Few moments you may be interested in: [Sidecar container lifecycle changes in Kubernetes 1.18](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-sidecars/)

Comment: Are there any security implications? Especially of tcpdump?

Comment: Will this work well with istio sidecar?

Answer (score 0):

None that I'm aware of or can imagine. If it works for you - go for it.